# free falling charge to different observers

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, reference-frames, charge, free-fall

I'm really confused and hope to find the write answer 
for a free falling charge to a supported observer, will it radiate?
for a charge at rest to a free falling observer, will it radiate?
for a charge at rest to supported observer, will it radiate?

Comment: @CountTo10 I read the article but i think its advanced for me ,, I wanted the answer for my question for my school article,, its about the paradox of charged particle in a gravitational field 
should I search more for faraday tensor ? would it help?

Comment: @CountTo10 no it's not about the redshift radiation 
it's about this 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_a_charge_in_a_gravitational_field

Comment: I have deleted my previous answer. I would consider heavily editing this question. Perhaps, "Why don't stationary charges in a gravitational field radiate?" is more along the lines of what you want to know? Additionally, the article you link contains the answer to your question. I would also include your understanding of this answer, and where exactly it you can no longer follow it.

Comment: The key is to the paradox is to realize that the laws of electrodynamics, the Maxwell equations, hold only in an inertial frame, and a revolving Earth is **not** an inertial frame, because it accelerates in a circular orbit.  If you can develop it from there, because I can't do the homework problem for you, or the answer below incorporates  that, then you are halfway there. Best of luck with it.

Comment: @CountTo10 my homework was only talking about the falling charge and this one is easy ,, my problem was the charge in rest from different observers! (that I didn't understand)
thank you, you let me notice that it is not included in my homework , my wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

All cases that we know of where an electrically charged particle radiates (electromagnetic radiation or photons) as a result of acceleration is where the force that causes the acceleration is produced by electromagnetism.

An electrically charged particle does not radiate electromagnetic fields when it experiences acceleration due to gravity. So a free falling electrically charged particle would not radiate. One way to see this is the fact that one can transform the acceleration away by allowing the observer to fall with the particle. In that case, the scenario is indistinguishable from the case where both are floating in free space with no forces acting on them.

The case where the charge particle is somehow suspended differs in that an electromagnetic force is needed to do the suspension. So there would then be an interaction between the charged particle and this force, but this is an electromagnetic interaction and not gravity.